# What do greyed out items in folder Properties Window in TortoiseSVN mean?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I see the *TortoiseSVN > Properties* for a folder to view the 'Properties Window', I see some of the property-values are greyed out. What does grey color signify here?

Is is to highlight that these properties have been inherited from the parent folder (if such property inheritance works for SVN folders)?

Comment: Show sample and version on TSVN - I can't see it with my TSVN 1.8 and  global-ignores